# Проблема с Matlab, функция tf

Tags: математика, matlab

Есть пример использования функции tf MatLab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно записать похожую функцию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Практически все получается, но пишет коеф возле 5s, чего мне не нужно. Не знаю какой синтаксис использовать, чтобы исключить значение.

Comment: В функцию необходимо вводить коэффициенты в порядке убывания соответствующих степеней, если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Каким образом можно сделать ? Не подскажите? Насколько я понял, сколько значений, столько и коэффициентов. То есть пропустить какой-то не получается

Comment: сложите два члена с первой степенью

Comment: Кстати да, а то, что у Вас в знаменателе не приведены подобные члены – это нормально?

Comment: Делал по примеру, в мат лабе не сильно разбираюсь. А похожих примеров не находил,

Comment: Попробуйте вот так `W1 = tf(12, [2 0 11 0 7 0])`.

Comment: Только что-то мне подсказывает, что у Вас в задании опечатка, и у `s` с коэффициентом `5` потеряна четвертая степень.

Comment: Не думаю что опечатка, вот такие примерно все задания. без некоторых степеней http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/779c2-clip-10kb.png?nocache=1

Comment: Тогда вспомните школьную математику, приведите подобные слагаемые и выпишите все коэффициенты при степенях получившегося многочлена, от большей степени к меньшей. Собственно я выше это уже сделал.